# JQuery selector for domain list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in my code that I need to modify links in my page, it looks something like this:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    // code here related to HREF attr
});
$('form').each(function(){
    // Code relate to the TARGET attr
});
```

I need to apply this function on all the links and targets of forms pointing to some specific domains. Let's say I have a list like this one: `www.example.com,www.domain.com,www.anotherdomain.com`

How can I modify the selector in a way it could apply it only to links and form pionting to the domains in the list?

Comment: You can use `indexOf`

Comment: Modify the code instead of the selector, this could work

Comment: Check out the updated answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter`:

```
var $exampleComLinks = $('a').filter(function() {
  return this.href.indexOf('https://example.com') == 0
      || this.href.indexOf('https://example2.com') == 0
      || this.href.indexOf('https://example3.com') == 0;
});
```

Or simple if statement:

```
$('a').each(function() {
  if (this.href.indexOf('https://example.com') == 0
      || this.href.indexOf('https://example2.com') == 0
      || this.href.indexOf('https://example3.com') == 0) {
    console.log('do something this $(this)');
  }
});
```

Using [@Praveen Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462627/praveen-kumar)'s `domainList` approach:

```
var domainsList = ["www.example.com", "www.domain.com", "www.anotherdomain.com"];
$('a').each(function () {
    if (domainsList.indexOf($(this).attr("href").replace(/https?:\/\/([^\/]*).*/gi, "$1")) > -1)
        // Do it.
});
$('form').each(function () {
    // Code relate to the TARGET attr
    if (domainsList.indexOf($(this).attr("href").replace(/https?:\/\/([^\/]*).*/gi, "$1")) > -1)
        // Do it.
});
```

Comment: I linke the last one. Let'st try it.

Answer (score 1):

If the targets are site url I suggest to add http:// or https:// and then (elsewhere you have to remove http:// from attr("target") or href when comparing.):

```
var domains="http://www.example.com,http://www.domain.com,http://www.anotherdomain.com";
$('a').each(function(){
    if (domains.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) > -1)
});
$('form').each(function(){
    if (domains.indexOf($(this).attr("target")) > -1)
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `== 0` istead of `>= -1`?

Comment: Thank you. Non of them. But it should be >-1 .corrected! @Kenny Lajara

Comment: @andlrc You are Strongly right. But the question was not general to this extent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new RegExp()` with parameter array list joined with separator `"|"`, `RegExp.prototype.test()`

```
var list = ["www.example.com","www.domain.com","www.anotherdomain.com"];

$("a, form").each(function(i, el) {
  if (new RegExp(list.join("|")).test(this.href || this.target)) {
    // do stuff
  }
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xkjpxd6L/

Comment: _"This will not work since $(this).attr('href') is likely to contain subdirectories."_? Not certain what you mean?

Comment: I think he mean that the link not need to be pointi to the hompage of the domains.

Comment: @KennyLajara Do `href` of `<a>` and `target` of `<form>` have values equal to those in array described at OP _"Let's say I have a list like this one: www.example.com,www.domain.com,www.anotherdomain.com"_? Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: No, If `domain.com` is in the array, I need to apply th function also to the links pointing to `http://domain.com/file.html` and `http://domain.com/anotherfile.aspx`

Comment: @guest271314 Let me ask you, How do you make an external link without a protocol? Your solution assumes no protocol is specified, and also assumes no pathname is specified.

Comment: @andlrc Add the protocol, though that is not necessary. For example, type `www.example.com/` at address bar and press `Enter`. See updated post

Comment: @andlrc No, it should not. Will create a jsfiddle to demonstrate

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry, my bad.

Comment: @KennyLajara Does `js` at post not return expected results?

Comment: @guest271314 Kind of. If I have `domain.com` in the list and `example.com` is not, I wouldn't expect it to process a link to `http://example.com?var=domain.com` and it does. Is not a bad answer cuz maybe I could be more specific when asked, but I changed the selected answer cuz I think it is implicit on the _"pointing to some specific domains"_ part. Anyway, thanks for your time and help, you keep my upvote. =)